# Display Value in Remix

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, events, arrays

I am a newbie in Solidity. Below is the simple Solidity source code

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.21; 

contract CAT {
    event XYZ (uint Z ) ;
    uint[] x;  
    uint a ;

function f(uint[]  memoryArray) public returns (uint[] ){
       x = memoryArray; 
      uint[]  y = x; 
      y.length = 2 ;       // line 1
      a = y.length ; 
      emit XYZ ( a  );
     return x ; 
  }
}
```

I use Remix. I deployed the contract and I am able to enter the value of `memoryArray1` .

[image]

However , I used event and emit thinking that after deploying I will see the value of `a` in the remix on the left hand side   but nothing like that is showing there. It means I am completely missing something there. Can anyone please let me know what do I need to add so that I also get to see the value of a in remix .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show the value outside your smart contract (in this case seeing it in remix IDE) you must use `view` keyword. It are read-only function, which ensures that state variables cannot be modified after calling them.

**IMPORTANT**: The best practice says that you must use `view` function only for read the variable from your smart contract.

In this case, you're implementing a logic before reading the array and you'll spend more gas for this operation.

You can consider the option to implement a `getter()` function that permit you to read the array value.

An example to adjust your original smart contract is in this way:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.4.21; 

contract CAT {
    event XYZ (uint Z ) ;
    uint[] x;  
    uint a ;

    function f(uint[] memoryArray) public {
        x = memoryArray; 
        uint[] storage y = x; 
        y.length = 2;
        a = y.length; 
        emit XYZ (a);
    }

    // NOTE: Getter() function
    function getValue() external view returns(uint[]) {
        return x;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this info , by the way is there any way to see the value without using getter function ?